# Is there a way in conda to list only explicitly installed packages without the packages that were installed as dependencies?

Tags: conda

How can I list only explicitly installed packages in conda for particular environment? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Check the [docs for `conda list`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html).

Comment: @AMC I have not found any information about in in `conda list`.

Comment: Looks like there's a feature request: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4545

Answer (score 35):

The page that @Sjlver's comment links to (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4545#issuecomment-616410225) has an answer.

`conda env export --from-history`

Please note that you need [`conda >=4.7.12`](https://github.com/conda/conda/commit/33154e2d417d8d1079614c46ca9ed90756cc1932#diff-a6ad37ef282990c86a1bb4c9ec9ed188f206c977df2b3ecc37498933afb079daR72-R78) (released 2019) for `--from-history` (though you can use a newer conda to export an environment created with an older one).

Comment: Thanks it indeed list all manually installed packages!!

Comment: Doesn't show the pip packages. How to get those as well?

Comment: @quest: This does not seem to be included atm (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8372)